# Oracle Text: Nested Near statements

Tags: oracle, indexing, full-text-search

I need to find documents in an Oracle Text index that satisfies multiple proximity conditions. For example, the word "cat" near the word "biologist" and then that combination near the word "Idaho". Is there any way to do this other than having three "Near" statements connected with "And"; such as, "near((cat, biologist), 10, FALSE) and near((cat, Idaho), 10, FALSE) and near((biologist, Idaho), 10, False)"?

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cqoper.htm#i997808

It seems that you can specify as many words as you want:

```
NEAR((cat,biologist,Idaho),10,FALSE)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Your solution will mostly work if I have the same proximity; however, I will be using other phrases that have different near maxes, such as, "near((cat, biologist), 5, FALSE) and near((cat, Idaho), 10, FALSE) and near((biologist, Idaho), 10, False)"